# Facebook Developer - LoginError : Asking for a code but no code delivered

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to create an app that connects to my Facebook account.

I followed this YouTube Tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrAXmZkOpJI
It's pretty good, everything worked well until I clicked the `LoginButton`.

Here's what happens :

When I start the App , everything is ok : Nothing in the `LogCat`. 
The button is shown.

I click the button ( Tried it on my phone and on Android Studio Emulator, same thing happens )

When I click, a window pops-up and says exactly this :

> " To connect to your account, open the Facebook app on your mobile device and check for notifications - OR - Visit Facebook.com/device and enter the code shown above "

But i have no code shown.

So I can't connect to my account since this window pops-up everytime I press the button. Even on my phone and with my personnal Facebook account, I have no code / notifications.

**MainActivity.java** :

```
package fr.example.stian.logintest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoginButton loginButton;
    TextView textView;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_btn);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                textView.setText("Login succes\n" +
                loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                textView.setText("Login canceled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                textView.setText("Error during login");
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fr.example.stian.logintest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Build.gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.example.stian.logintest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'

}
```

**strings.xml** :

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">LoginTest</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">my_app_id</string>
    <string name="facebook_client_token">facebook_client_token</string>
</resources>
```

**Error LogCat** :

```
12-15 10:19:41.177 3014-3075/fr.example.stian.logintest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa350540: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaaa4b910)
12-15 10:19:41.265 3014-3075/fr.example.stian.logintest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa350540: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaaa4b910)
12-15 10:19:41.320 3014-3075/fr.example.stian.logintest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa350540: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaaa4b910)
12-15 10:19:41.387 3014-3075/fr.example.stian.logintest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa350540: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaaa4b910)
12-15 10:19:41.426 3014-3075/fr.example.stian.logintest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa350540: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaaa4b910)
12-15 10:20:01.471 3014-3075/fr.example.stian.logintest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa350540: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaaa4b910)
12-15 10:20:01.472 3014-3075/fr.example.stian.logintest E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae66de00
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err: (#3) To use this feature, you must enable "Login from Devices" in your app's Facebook Login settings under the Products section of Facebook for Developers website.
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:218)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:173)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:95)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at fr.example.stian.logintest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:54)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-15 10:20:01.486 3014-3014/fr.example.stian.logintest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-15 10:20:01.489 3014-3075/fr.example.stian.logintest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa350540: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaaa4b910)
12-15 10:20:01.498 3014-3075/fr.example.stian.logintest E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae66e760
```

**EDIT :**

This button is enabled :[image: Android Section in the Facebook Developer Console]

Comment: You sure you've followed the procedure in facebook developer console completely to use the login feature?

Comment: Yes, I followed the tutorial on YouTube and the procedure in the Facebook Developer Quickstart Guide, but same error.

Comment: Did you try enabling the "Login from Devices" button in the console and loging in again?

Comment: If you are talking about the Settings -> General ; Android Section, "Single authentification" button, with the description " Will be launched from Android Devices ", yes, it is enabled. 
But I can't find any other button related to "Login from devices" in the console.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes Check the edit, I added the picture of the button I'm talking about.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about that button. This button is in Products>Facebook login>Settings section( "Client OAuth Settings" part of the right side screen, to be precise).

Comment: (Please switch your FB language to English before taking such screenshots, makes it easier for everyone here.)

Comment: Find it like this image :[Login from Devices location](https://i.imgur.com/TlhYgwm.png)

Comment: Sorry for the picture. 

Now it's working on the emulator. It's giving me a code.
But on my phone, I still don't have the code showing.

Comment: Ok, it is working now on my phone. 
I just had to re-Build the project, and install it twice on my phone and it worked. 
Needed to go the website facebook.com/device **with my phone** and not with the PC, and then enter the code I had on my phone when starting the app.

Comment: Dude, don't expose your app-id here in the question, better remove it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this image , follow these steps **to enable Login for Devices.**

[image]

Hope this will Help.

Comment: Same answer as the comment above : 
Now it's working on my emulator ( I'm getting the code ), but not on my phone.

Comment: Happy to help you

Comment: For the answer, check the comment above for more information ! Thank you ! :)